# What IC to use for single Li ion charging / load sharing for a 250mA load that can be left plugged in to USB?

Tags: circuit-design, integrated-circuit, battery-charging, power-electronics

You wouldn't think it would be so complicated, but I'm self-taught in EE and the rabbit holes just keep getting deeper the more I investigate. Simply put, I'm trying to build a LED lamp that is both rechargeable (3400 mAh 18650 li-ion) that can be safely ran AND recharged (read: automatic power path) when left plugged into USB. I'm using [these 1W SMD LEDs](https://amz.run/5okn), and the goal is to produce equal brightness when battery/USB powered. Eventually, I plan to have a PCBs manufactured for mass production, so cost/simplicity/reliability/safety is paramount.

I first considered using the readily available TP4056 charging boards (03962A), but they do not have load sharing functionality. I considered replicating that circuitry [with these improvements](https://tinyl.io/6iVh) and adding [load sharing functionality](https://tinyl.io/6iVd), and then ran into the issue of having to drop the 5V USB bypass to match the 3.7V normally output from the battery. For this, adding either resistors in series feels inefficient, and adding a switching regulator with inductors to the system feels like I've over-engineered the whole thing, and probably incorrectly.

I've ran every parametric search combination I can think of and read dozens of datasheets. But it's become overwhelming having to self-educate for every possible design strategy simply to eliminate it. Ideally, there's an IC that can handle most or all of this in a single package. A few that seem promising include:

- RT9525 - Linear Single Cell Li-Ion Battery Charger with Auto Power Path
- MP2607 - Li + LINEAR Charger With System Power Path Management, 1.5A MAX Charge Current
- NCP1851 - Switching Battery Charger, 1.6 A, with Power Path Management
- BQ2429x - x I2C Controlled 3-A Single Cell USB Charger With Narrow VDC
  Power Path Management and Adjustable Voltage USB OTG

The fewer external components required (and less chance of incorrect design) to make this work, the better. Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: So how do the LEDs connect to battery now then? With a resistor? How does it handle constant brightness as battery voltage is not 3.7V but anything between fully charged 4.2V and fully discharged about 2.7V ?

Comment: Honestly I haven't addressed that. I guess I mean matching the nominal voltage. Maybe this consideration warrants passing both the battery  and the USB power through a buck converter so that the output voltage is consistent.

Comment: Use a constant-current buck (or boost if you put a couple of LEDs in series) converter to drive your LEDs. That way the exact supply voltage doesn't matter much and your device will operate with constant output over a much wider range.